# Is it possible to put an "if statement" inside a "N.times{}" bracket in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

IN RUBY,
for example, if you wanted to print the first 25 integers, and put ", " between the 1st and last integers in the output (to clean it up a little bit), could you write something like the code below? (I deliberately didn't use while/for loops.)

```
N = 25

N.times{|i| print("#{i}")
 if i > 0 and i < 25
   print ", "
}
```

If this has already been answered, please redirect me to the old post? Thanks :)

Comment: This would literally take less time to try than to post the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Though the easiest way to answer these questions is to try them in irb.  There are some small problems with your counting logic.

```
25.times do |i|
  print "#{i}"
  if i >= 0 and i < 24
    print ","
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is just an example, but it's worth noting that what you would actually want to use for this is [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
irb(main):001:0> [*0..25].join(", ")
=> "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25"
```

Answer (score 0):

Josh Y.'s join example is nicer, but here's your method reduced to a single line.

```
N.times {|i| print"#{i}#{', ' if i>=0 and i<N-1}"}
```